# Test RAID array read write speeds from boot disk

Tags: performance, raid, esxi

I have a VMware ESXi server with a local RAID 5 datastore formatted with VMFS.  The RAID controller is a DELL PERC H710 hardware controller and the server is an R620.  I get abysmal write speeds, around 15MB/s from within ESXi.  I want to rule out ESXi being the problem.  Is there a boot disk I can boot from to get some metrics/diagnostics on my RAID array?  I am wondering if it being formatted with VMFS would be a problem since it's a proprietary file system.

Answer (score 3):

You can always test read speeds with any old Linux live CD (such as [SystemRescueCD](http://sysresccd.org)), but to test write speeds, you need to be able to mount the VMFS volume with write access. Are you sure you're actually using the PERC controller, and not just running *software* RAID-5? Software RAID-5 is indeed very slow, and since you have a hardware RAID controller, it'd be a crying shame not to use it.

There exists a Java-based VMFS Version 3 read-only driver (open source and for Windows or Linux), but you can't write to it, so you can't test write speed.

I don't have a good solution that doesn't involve either shrinking or deleting your VMFS partition and testing with another filesystem (such as XFS) on a Linux live CD.

If you are able to use ESXi to shrink the VMFS partition, you can create a new XFS partition in the freed up space and benchmark that from a Linux live CD.